Zenject - Restrict the usage of a class when binding with an interface
Using zenject I have class, lets say A. Then another class B which implements interface IB. I Want to bind the interface of B (only the interface) in the container as single, but bind the whole class B when injected to A also as single. So at the end there's only one instance of B.
So I want to allow class A to use B property but any other classes cannot inject B, they can only inject the interface (IB).
Is that possible without using Resolve in the InstallBindings method (as it's not recommended)?

Don't nail me on it (not a zenject expert) .. afaik you can simply bind to multiple types like e.g. Bind(typeof(B), typeof(IB)).To<B>(); whether and how you can explicitly restrict this idk tbh .. but you could simply make your A get a B injected while in the others you only inject IB .. a bit the other way round .. otherwise you'd probably have to go into injection scopes

Easy mode:
public override void InstallBindings() {
    var b = new B();
    Container.Bind<B>().FromInstance(b).AsTransient().WhenInjectedInto<A>();
    Container.Bind<IB>().FromInstance(b).AsSingle();
    Container.Bind<A>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
}

Note that here it doesn't matter what scope you specify (though Zenject will not allow you to use two AsSingle), it is always the same instance anyway. The rest, I think, is self-explanatory.

Hard mode:
public override void InstallBindings() {
    Container.Bind<IB>().To<B>().AsSingle();

    Container
        .Bind<B>()
        .FromResolveGetter<IB>(_ => (B)Container.Resolve<IB>())
        .WhenInjectedInto<A>();

    Container.Bind<A>().AsTransient().NonLazy();
}

Zenject offers safe alternatives to the direct use of Container.Resolve in InstallBindings:

FromResolve, which is not of much use here as it only resolves bound types,
and FromResolveGetter, which allows us to resolve the binding ourselves, including using Container.Resolve in a safe manner.

Here it is relatively simple: IB, the type that is already bound to B, is resolved and then cast to its concrete type. But still be careful with the types. The type you specify to FromResolveGetter should be the same type you are using in Container.Resolve while the type returned by it should be the type you want to have. It is really easy to misuse types here, and Zenject will spam you with stack overflow or circular dependency error messages, which aren't of much help explaining where the problem is.
The use of the resulting binding is restricted to only class A by WhenInjectedInto<A>().
Also notice that this binding doesn't need a scope, as B is already restricted by the previous one.
And, as a side note, the same is possible for interfaces too. But depending on how interfaces relate, casting can become somewhat crazy, e.g. (IB2)(B)Container.Resolve<IB>().
